# calendário retorna data mm/dd/yyyy em vez de dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: vba

Estou a usar um calendário que, independentemente das alterações que faça, retorna sempre a data mm/dd/yyy, quando se pretende que seja dd/mm/yyyy.

O código abaixo não é meu, foi retirado da net:

```
Option Explicit
Dim vDateSelectedVar As Date

Public Property Get SelectDate() As Date
    SelectDate = vDateSelectedVar
End Property



Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'A data inicial é a atual:
    lblHoje = "Hoje: " & Format(Date, "dd/MM/aaaa")
    sb = Year(Date) * 12 + Month(Date)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    'Impede que se dê Unload no formulário, caso contrário a linha que testa
    'frm.Tag na linha seguinte do módulo mdlCalendário dará erro, pois o objeto
    'deixará de existir. Ao invés de dar Unload, usa-se Hide para o objeto
    'continuar a existir na memória.
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        Hide
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub lblHoje_Click()
    'Quando se clica no Label do dia atual, o calendário atualiza-se
    'para o mês atual.

    'O modo de cálculo do mês em questão é o número de meses.
    'Como um ano possui 12 meses, o valor da ScrollBar é o número
    'total de meses:
    sb = Year(Date) * 12 + Month(Date)
End Sub

Private Sub sb_Change()
    'Deve-se atualizar o calendário ao alterar a ScrollBar.
    'O valor do calendário é uma divisão inteira (observe o símbolo \)
    'de anos e o resto do valor por 12 como mês:
    Atualizar DateSerial(sb \ 12, sb Mod 12, 1)
End Sub

Private Sub Atualizar(dt As Date)
    'Rotina que atualiza todos os Label do calendário

    Dim l As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim cInício As Long
    Dim dtDia As Date
    Dim ctrl As control

    lblMêsAno = Format(dt, "mmmm yyyy")

    For l = 1 To 6 'Linhas do calendário
        For c = 1 To 7 'Colunas do calendário
            Set ctrl = Controls("l" & l & "c" & c)
            'O entendimento da linha abaixo é fundamental para entender como todos os
            'labels foram povoados:
            dtDia = DateSerial(Year(dt), Month(dt), (l - 1) * 7 + c - Weekday(dt) + 1)
            ctrl.Caption = Format(Day(dtDia), "00")
            ctrl.Tag = dtDia
            'Dias de um mês diferente do mês visualizado ficarão na cor cinza claro:
            If Month(dtDia) <> Month(dt) Then
                ctrl.ForeColor = &H808080
            Else
                ctrl.ForeColor = &H0
            End If
            'Realçar dia atual presente, caso esteja visível no calendário:
            If dtDia = Date Then
                ctrl.ForeColor = &HFF&
            End If
        Next c
    Next l

End Sub
```

o que poderá estar errado? O Excel é o 2016 em Windows 10.

Comment: Você está usando VBA? Qual seu código que utilizou para fazer a conversão? Onde está dando o erro? Acho que poderia melhorar a pergunta utilizando seu código para facilitar a resposta.

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas o que pode estar dando erro é a utilização do `DateSerial`. Pois o VBA utiliza o padrão americano de datas, causando sempre muitos erros quando outro padrão é adotado...

Answer (score 2):

Em txtData altere para,
DateValue(txtData.Value)

Assim a Data ficará Correta (dd/mm/yyy) Ex: 21/08/2020